# Half life 2 and other games lag a lot

Tags: 16.04, games, amd-graphics

I have an old laptop running Ubuntu 16.04. It has 2x Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU T7200 @ 2.00GHz, 2gb of ram, and ATI RV515 integrated graphics. The computer has no trouble in day to day use, but I just can't seem to figure out why it only has problems with some games.

EDIT - I forgot to mention that it had little to no problem running hl2 on Windows vista.

Comment: Maybe because of something called "compatibility port". They sometimes are bad.

Comment: Run hl2.exe with parameters -win98 -dexlevel 81  . Does it help?

Comment: Sadly it doesn't help.